# Can Electron apps handle separate windows?

Tags: electron, capacitor

Is it possible to create an Electron(+ Capacitor) application that has a "quick add" - feature, as you might know it from Things or Trello?

[image: Trello Quick add]

I'm simply talking about the possibility to press a shortcut while the app is not in focus.
And just a specific window will come to the foreground. Not the main Electron app.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a global shortcut using electron's `globalShortcut` module. See the following example from [electron's documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut):

```js
const { app, globalShortcut } = require('electron')

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  // Register a 'CommandOrControl+X' shortcut listener.
  const ret = globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+X', () => {
    console.log('CommandOrControl+X is pressed')
  })

  if (!ret) {
    console.log('registration failed')
  }

  // Check whether a shortcut is registered.
  console.log(globalShortcut.isRegistered('CommandOrControl+X'))
})
```

Don't forget to unregister it before the app quits:

```js
app.on('will-quit', () => {
  // Unregister a shortcut.
  globalShortcut.unregister('CommandOrControl+X')

  // Unregister all shortcuts.
  globalShortcut.unregisterAll()
})
```